# Add Single Quotes around a list in Ansible

Tags: variables, join, ansible, single-quotes

I have a list of items services and each needs to be wrapped in single quotes to configure some parameters.

The simplest solution I saw posted was:

```
"{{services | match('quote') | join(' OR ')}}"
```

This only wrapped the first element in the list in a single quote but not the remaining.

I also tried some variations of match regex.

Finally I tried adding the single quote manually in the data source, then joining.  The first element retained the single quotes but subsequent were stripped off? What is going on here?

Right now they are static from the inventory
i.e.:

```yaml
---
inventory:
  hosts:
    host1:
      procs:
      - splunkd.*
      services:
      - 'some service name'
      - 'another service name'
      - 'SplunkForwarder'
```

I need the end result to be

```
"Name='some service name' OR Name='another service name'"
```

Currently with the services single quoted in variable the quotes are stripped or ignored.

Result

```
Name=some service or Name=another service
```

Comment: could you show your playbook and what have you try...and show the result waited

Comment: Right now they are static from the inventory
ie:
`
---
inventory:
  hosts:
    host1:
      procs:
      - splunkd.*
      services:
      - 'some service name'
      - 'another service name'
      - 'SplunkForwarder'
`

These details don't matter though.  I need the end result to be "Name='some service name' OR Name='another service name'

etc

Comment: you have just one double quote in your result?

Comment: @U880D it's enough that I am asking for a result that is specific.  that is not hardcoded, it is concatenated from a list. You're looking in the wrong direction and not providing anything useful.

Comment: `map('quote')` and not `match('quote')`. The behaviour you see might also be because the quotes won't be added if they are not relevant (e.g. the service is a single word, with nothing that is an issue for a shell variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could cut your problem by using loop:

```
  tasks:
    - name: set var
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ result | d('') + _i + _o }}"
      loop: "{{ services }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: yes
      vars:
        _i: "Name='{{ item }}'"
        _o: "{{ '' if  ansible_loop.last else ' OR ' }}"

    - name: display result
      debug:
        var: result
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": "Name='some service name' OR Name='another service name' OR Name='SplunkForwarder'"
}
```

with your vars:

```
- name: Join services   
  set_fact:     
    joined_services: "{{ joined_services | d('') + service + serviceAppend }}"     
  loop: "{{ services }}"     
  loop_control:       
    extended: yes     
  vars:
    service: "'{{ item }}'"
    serviceAppend: "{{ '' if  ansible_loop.last else ' OR ' }}"
```

Comment: Getting an error that the var is undefined:
`code
- name: Join services
  set_fact:
    joined_services: "{{ joined_services | d('') + service + serviceAppend }}"
    loop: "{{ services }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: yes
    vars: 
      service: "'{{ item }}'"
      serviceAppend: "{{ '' if  ansible_loop.last else ' OR ' }}"
`

 FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'service' is undefined

Comment: i am pretty sure you dont respect spaces with module argument and loop.. i have tested with your vars and no problem.. your error is coming because vars was not correctly written ..

Comment: You're right. Some YAML formatting on my part. Works wonderfully